# When Forward is a martingale under risk-neutral measure?

Tags: futures, forward, martingale

Why is such a proof for futures not suitable for a forward?

For futures we have:

$V_{t}$ is self-financing portfolio: $V_t = \frac{V_t}{B_t}B_t$, where $B_t$ is a riskless asset

Suppose $H_t$ - number of futures in portfolio, then

$dV_t = H_t df_t + \frac{V_t}{B_t} dB_t = H_t df_t + V_t r dt$, where $f_t$ - futures price
$d\frac{V_t}{B_t} = \frac{dV_t}{B_t} - \frac{V_t}{B_t^2}dB_t = \frac{V_t df_t + V_t r dt}{B_t} - \frac{V_t r}{B_t}dt = \frac{V_t}{B_t}df_t$

Since $V_t$ is self-financing and $B_t$ is numeraire, $f_t$ is a martingale under risk-neutral measure.

What would be the contradiction if we replace futures with forward in these calculations

Comment: quote forward prices are martingales under the forward measure, f. Compare with futures prices, which are martingales under the risk neutral measure. However if interest rates are deterministic, the two measure coincide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_measure